# Solving a SQL 1064 error when trying to retrieve my password for a locally developed Wordpress site?

Tags: sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am locally developing a Wordpress site and have forgotten my password. I went through `myphpadmin` to access the database and change it; however, I get a #1064 SQL error when I click 'edit' on my user entry.

The errant query is:
`SELECT * FROM "db"."users" WHERE ;`

When I change it to:
`SELECT * FROM "db"."users" WHERE ID = 1;`

...it returns my user entry in a list but does not open the graphical interface to edit it. When I then click 'edit' on the entry in the list, I once again get the 1064 SQL error because the query has reverted back to:

`SELECT * FROM "db"."users" WHERE ;`

How do I fix this so I can edit my password? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about executing simple update:

```
UPDATE `db`.`users`
SET col_name_pass = HASH(pass) -- or clear text pass???
WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: Please pardon this basic question - would I type the new password where you wrote "pass" - `HASH(newpassword)`?

Comment: I don't know how you store passwords in your db. If in clear text simply put `SET password_column = 'my_new_strong_password'`. If it is hashed, you need to know the method (SHA1,SHA2, MD5, ...) and calculate new one.

Comment: It appears to be hashed using MD5